# How does swift library hide its implementation

Tags: ios, swift

At certain point of time we might have tried to see the code for packages/library provided by apple for ios development. For example : UIViewController, SFSafariViewController, and so on.. When we move into file of these package/library we find something like this.

```
extension UIViewController {

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open var children: [UIViewController] { get }

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func addChild(_ childController: UIViewController)


    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func removeFromParent()

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func transition(from fromViewController: UIViewController, to toViewController: UIViewController, duration: TimeInterval, options: UIView.AnimationOptions = [], animations: (() -> Void)?, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? { get }

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? { get }

}
```

It is just part of what that file contains. But this is merely a method signature and these method has lot more in its implementation which is hidden from user access.

My question is

> How does this is possible? How can we hide or provide user only the
>   function signature to use and rest thing is hidden from user's eye?

Comment: Use a framework or static library, iOS is built out of frameworks, didn't I tell you this yesterday and provide you a tutorial link?

Comment: that thing was of no help to me. All of that has been done by me already. I am looking for something else. May be I am not clear in my self or I am not able to make others understand.

Comment: I think a framework or library is what you are looking for. It hides implementation but shows method signature. Anyway I dont think there are any more options, either share the code, the framework or the static library

Comment: I have created framework only. But when I add that pod in project all the individual files I can see that is present in my pod library. I am using cocoa pod. And Because that file is visible I can see the entire code.

Comment: dont ship your source code in the pod then, the pods are for open source software and usually checkout the whole project from git. you dont want that do dont provide a pod with the source code??

Comment: So then what is the alternate. That library is for public itself but it has some lines that should not be public. And as you are saying don't use pod so what should I look for?? I tried taking .framework file and zip it and added that file as http source for pod but again it shows entire file

Comment: Pods contain swift source files, PUBLIC code. Frameworks don't, you can only see the resources and header files which show the public facing classes, methods and properties but not their implementation. So you build your framework and you put the .framework file in a folder maybe with some documentation or something and zip it up and upload the resulting archive as a release on your website, or github page or whatever. If someone wants to use your framework they download and use it. Pods are mostly for use in public, open source software. yours it not public open source

Comment: maybe this might help: https://medium.com/onfido-tech/distributing-compiled-swift-frameworks-via-cocoapods-8cb67a584d57

Comment: @Scriptable I have added .framework folder to git. But when I install it then it does not get .framework folder in project.

Comment: how do you "install it"?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155791/pod-library-not-installing-properly @Scriptable

Comment: So you have put a .framework file in your pod and you cannot use it? you keep giving very limited information about what state your currently in with the project. I cannot help like this... update your question with exactly what you have done so far and what issue you are currently getting

Comment: @Scriptable I have created this new thread for this issue please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155791/pod-library-not-installing-properly

Answer (score 0):

**UIKit** is a framework so it has **Access Control**

From **docs.swift.org**

> Access control restricts access to parts of your code from code in
>   other source files and modules. This feature enables you to hide the
>   implementation details of your code, and to specify a preferred
>   interface through which that code can be accessed and used.

You can add framework to your project with **Access Control**

[Access Control document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html)

[Swift standard library](https://github.com/apple/swift)

In Swift Access Controls from **docs.swift.org**:

> **Open** access and public access enable entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a source file
>   from another module that imports the defining module. You typically
>   use open or public access when specifying the public interface to a
>   framework. The difference between open and public access is described
>   below.
>
> **Internal** access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.
>
> **File-private** access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use file-private access to hide the
>   implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those
>   details are used within an entire file.
>
> **Private** access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the
>   same file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a
>   specific piece of functionality when those details are used only
>   within a single declaration.

Comment: in the very first line it is written "code from code" that means you can visit that file and watch those implementations

Comment: Yes, Xcode shows only public methods. If you write a framework and set your public methods, they see your only public methods like how implementations. You can set private extensions or public extensions

Comment: But at the end this only hides access in your swift file.

Comment: If you are using compiled framework, you cannot access swift file