# Pod library not installing properly

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have a project XyzAbc with proj structure

```
--LICENSE
--XyzAbc
----XyzAbc.h
----Info.plist
----file1.swift
----file2.swift
--Products
----XyzAbc.framework
```

After building this project I pick this `XyzAbc.framework` and push it in github account that has folder structure

```
--XyzAbc.framework
--.gitignore
--LICENSE
--XyzAbc.podspec
--README.md
```

I created `XyzAbc.podspec` file in my local machine its structure is

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name           = ""
  s.version        = "0.1.1"
  s.summary        = ""
  s.description    = ""
  s.homepage       = ""
  s.swift_versions = "4.2"
  s.license        = {
    :type => "MIT",
    :file => "LICENSE"
  }
  s.author         = "xyyyy"
  s.platform       = :ios, "10.0"
  s.source         = {
:git => "https://github.com/xyz/pqr.git", # github link where I uploaded my compiled library
:tag => "0.1.1"
  }
  s.source_files        = "XyzAbc.framework/Headers/*.h"
  s.public_header_files = "XyzAbc.framework/Headers/*.h"
  s.vendored_frameworks = "XyzAbc.framework"
  s.framework           = 'Foundation'

end
```

I am refering this podspec file in my app like

```
target 'TestApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'XyzAbc', :path => "../../../../Desktop/XyzAbc.podspec"

end
```

But I am not able to see any header inside pod library. In my project TestApp it looks something like this

```
--Pods
----Podfile
----Development Pods
------XyzAbc
--------Pods
--------SupportFiles
--------<Frameworks is missing>
```

I tried using `:http` then when I provide zip `.framework` folder in http link, it is not working but when I provide unziped `.framework` folder then I am able to use this library.

I am following this https://medium.com/onfido-tech/distributing-compiled-swift-frameworks-via-cocoapods-8cb67a584d57

UPDATE - elaborated

Comment: You don't have to add the podspec `XyzAbc.podspec` in the **path** directory, the directory that works for me on the `path` is the root folder where the **podspec** is located

Comment: Does that matter? coz I am able to initiate install. Thing is same with your chnages.

Comment: I can't be too sure because I haven't tried shipping a **framework** only cocoapod. Maybe the header inside the framework is named differently?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, but `source_files` and `public_headers` should not be specified with a `vendored_framework`.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Can you explain me the use case of vendored framework? I was just following the article.